# Dependency Conflict When Installing chromadb on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, py-langchain, chromadb

I am trying to install chromadb in a Python virtual environment, but I'm encountering a series of dependency conflicts, particularly related to onnxruntime and others. The installation process does not complete due to these conflicts.

1. Updated pip: I updated pip to its latest version, expecting this might resolve any dependency issues.
2. Created a New Virtual Environment: Set up a fresh environment to avoid conflicts with existing packages, anticipating a smooth installation of chromadb.
3. Manually Installed onnxruntime: Installed onnxruntime>=1.14.1 before chromadb, hoping to preempt the mentioned dependency conflict.
4. Attempted Installing chromadb: Finally, tried installing chromadb, expecting these steps would have resolved any conflicts.

[image]

Actual Result: Despite these efforts, I still faced the same dependency conflicts, indicating that the issue remained unresolved.

Comment: please include your complete error message